# seleniumでGoogleを開こうとスクレイピングする際、WebdriveException:Message:chrome not reachableとでてしまい開けません

Tags: python, python3, selenium

プログラムの勉強を始めたばかりで、YouTubeや本などの模写？みたいのをしています。

スクレイピングの動画で下記のプログラムをうったところ、
WebdriveExceptionと出てしまいgoogleを開けませんでした。
seleniumやbrewなどのインストールはすませてあります。

```
browser.get('http://www.google.com./')
```

Comment: `下記のプログラム`というのが提示されていません。また`スクレイピングの動画`というのは参考にした資料と思われますが、それの紹介リンクも提示した方が良いでしょう。そして発生したエラーは略さず全て表示されたままをテキストで提示してください。それから`brew`ということはmacosでしょうか？どのような環境と版数で作業しているか等、これらのヘルプ記事を参考に正確な詳細を記述してください。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ちなみに対象URLは細かいtypoがあるようで、`https`の`s`が不足していたり、最後の`.com./`で`com`と`/`の間の`.`は余計では？

Comment: なお、タイトルに示されたエラーで検索するとこんな記事が見つかるので参考になるかもしれません。[【EC2】seleniumがスタックして処理が進まない（データ取得に時間がかかる）ときの対処法（selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: 　Message: chrome not reachable）](https://prograshi.com/language/python/ec2-selenium-chrome-not-reachable/), [Message: chrome not reachableのエラー対処　pythonでスクレイピング](https://satoki252595.com/2020/08/29/chrome-not-reachable/)

Comment: "browser.get('http://www.google.com./')"
Googleはスクレイピング禁止だったかと思いますので利用規約をご確認ください。